# Automatically resizing a custom plotting character?

Tags: r, plot, pch

Hey everybody I am hoping there is someone out there who can help me with plotting a custom made pch in R. In my case I am trying to create a graph relating to water quality over time. One way to monitor water quality is to use a secchi disc, which is basically a metal disc with quarters of the disc painted black and white (see the plot below).

So far I've been able to successfully create the disc and put it on a plot, but my problem comes with a stretching effect depending on the dimensions of the plot.

Here are the function I've used to create the disc so far:

```
# A circle function to draw a circle (pulled form another stackoverflow page)

circleFun <- function(center=c(0,0), diameter=1, npoints=100, start=0, end=2, filled=TRUE){
  tt <- seq(start*pi, end*pi, length.out=npoints)
  df <- data.frame(
    x = center[1] + diameter / 2 * cos(tt),
    y = center[2] + diameter / 2 * sin(tt)
  )
  if(filled==TRUE) { #add a point at the center so the whole 'pie slice' is filled
    df <- rbind(df, center)
  }
  return(df)
}

# and my function to create a secchi disc
secchiDisc = function(x,y,diameter = 1){
  quarterCircle1 = circleFun(c(x,y),diameter = diameter, start=0, end=0.5)
  quarterCircle3 = circleFun(c(x,y),diameter = diameter, start=1, end=1.5)
  fullCircle = circleFun(c(x, y), diameter, start=0, end=2)
  polygon(quarterCircle1$x,quarterCircle1$y,col="black")
  polygon(quarterCircle3$x,quarterCircle3$y,col="black")
  polygon(fullCircle$x,fullCircle$y)
}

# make a plot to show what it looks like
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(0,0,pch = "")
secchiDisc(0,0)
```

[image]

```
# create data frame 
data = as.data.frame(list(Year = 1970:2015,
                          Depth = rnorm(46,3,1)))

# and create a time series plot showing changes in depth over time
plot(data$Year,data$Depth,pch="",ylim = c(7,0))
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  secchiDisc(data$Year[i],data$Depth[i])
}
```

So here is how it looks when plotting with a time series:
[image]

And obviously I can just stretch the plot horizontally until it cleans up, but I was wondering if anyone out there has any suggestions on how to automatically get the disc to re-size based on the plot?
[image]

I've tried to customize the circle functions to allow for a stretch effect, but to no avail. I think one of the problems with the 'stretch effect' approach is that I still want the disc to appear circular, but I couldn't get the diameter of the circle to change independently of the x or y dimension.

Another thought I had was to save a blank plot of the secchi disc as a png file and try to plot the imported file. Thoughts on this approach?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a solution. If not, I must be very close. The problem is that in your function, the diameter is the same for the x-axis and the y-axis, independently of range of data. Said differently, the range of the Years axis is 45 and the range of the Depth axis is ~5. When you try to apply the same diameter in units to both axis, the shape of the circle is deformed. My solution is to  calculate a ratio of the ranges of the x-axis and y-axis. The ratio is then applied to the `sin` line in `circleFun`. I'm not sure if the ratio should be divided by `sqrt(2)` but it works. Also, you should not resize your plotting window manually after plotting the chart. use `win.graph` in windows or `quartz()` in mac before the plot.

```
    # A circle function to draw a circle (pulled form another stackoverflow page)

circleFun <- function(center=c(0,0), diameter=1, npoints=100, start=0, end=1, filled=TRUE,ratio=1){
  tt <- seq(start*pi, end*pi, length.out=npoints)
  df <- data.frame(
    x = center[1] + diameter / 2 * cos(tt),
    y = center[2] + diameter/ratio / 2 * sin(tt)
  )
  if(filled==TRUE) { #add a point at the center so the whole 'pie slice' is filled
    df <- rbind(df, center)
  }
  return(df)
}

# and my function to create a secchi disc
secchiDisc = function(x,y,diameter = 1,ratio=1){
  quarterCircle1 = circleFun(c(x,y),diameter = diameter, start=0, end=0.5,ratio=ratio)
  quarterCircle3 = circleFun(c(x,y),diameter = diameter, start=1, end=1.5,ratio=ratio)
  fullCircle = circleFun(c(x, y), diameter, start=0, end=2,ratio=ratio)
  polygon(quarterCircle1$x,quarterCircle1$y,col="black")
  polygon(quarterCircle3$x,quarterCircle3$y,col="black")
  polygon(fullCircle$x,fullCircle$y)
}

data = as.data.frame(list(Year = 1970:2015,
                          Depth = rnorm(46,3,1)))

xx <-diff(range(data$Year))
yy <-diff(range(data$Depth))
ratio=(xx/yy)/sqrt(2)
plot(data$Year,data$Depth,pch="")
for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
  secchiDisc(data$Year[i],data$Depth[i],diameter = 1.5,ratio=ratio)
}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks fantastic. Thanks so much for your help.